# Ubuntu 18.04 on Acer TravelMate P449-M Installation problems

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi

Iam trying to install Ubuntu on my Acer-Laptop.

This laptop normally runs with Windows 10, but I chose the option to remove Windows from my disk, which was offered by the Ubuntu-Installer.

I can successfully install Ubuntu from my USB-Stick. When the installation proccess is done, Iam getting the expected message that everything is fine and I should now reboot my computer.

However, when I now reebot my Computer, Iam getting the following error:

```
No Bootable Device
```

My BIOS boot-options are the following:

```
Boot Mode: UEFI
Secure Boot: Enabled
Boot priority order:

1. HDD0: LIETON CV3-8D256
2. HDD1: WDC WD10SPCK-21KHST0
...
```

Ubuntu should be installed on both disks, since I tried both of them via Ubuntu-Installer.

I tried the following things:

- Using [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), as its described in [this thread](https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/nach-ubuntu-installation-no-bootable-device/) (german language)
- Installing Ubuntu Version 18.04 again multiple times
- Installing Ubuntu Version 17.04 multiple times
- Downloaded mand different images from different websites and reflashed my USB-Sticks multiple times using [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/)

but nothing worked.

I want to say that I do **NOT** care about the data on my disks. I got multiple backups and everything on them can be destroyed if needed.

I also want to say that I do nearly know nothing about how Bootloaders and all this stuff works, Iam normally used to just plug my stick in, install the OS and everything works fine, but it seems like the ouput of the following commands may be interesting for you, since those have been requested on other forums:

```
sudo parted -l:

Model: ATA WDC WD10SPCX-21K (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   1000GB  1000GB  ext4


Model: ATA LITEON CV3-8D256 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   256GB  256GB  ext4


Model: Intenso Rainbow Line (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 15.7GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  15.7GB  15.7GB  primary  fat32        boot, lba
```

**And:**

```
sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/loop0: 1.7 GiB, 1831378944 bytes, 3576912 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 86.6 MiB, 90759168 bytes, 177264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 140 MiB, 146841600 bytes, 286800 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 1.6 MiB, 1691648 bytes, 3304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 12.2 MiB, 12804096 bytes, 25008 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 21 MiB, 22003712 bytes, 42976 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 3.3 MiB, 3411968 bytes, 6664 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6A40AD4B-F3F8-4E57-891B-BC5654552831

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624 1953523711 1952473088  931G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdb: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 5703C2E4-D776-4B90-AD1D-E20A50DF66E8

Device       Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1     2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2  1050624 500117503 499066880  238G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdc: 14.7 GiB, 15728640000 bytes, 30720000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00863f20

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *     2048 30719999 30717952 14.7G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Can anybody tell me whats wrong here?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: All Acer require you to set UEFI password and enable "trust" on the  grub/ubuntu .efi boot files in the ESP from within UEFI. http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947&p=13369742#post13369742 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2358003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And as always, a couple minutes after I ask a question, I find a solution (btw. my internet-connection went down, thats why Iam asnwering that late.):

Open your BIOS (In my case press F2 while booting)

Got to the Security-Tab and look for `Select an UEFI file as trusted
for executing`. If its disabled, like in my case, just create a security password.

select an UEFI-File as trusted and reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI article holds all the information you need to complete a successful setup.

Comment: Please note that at this moment your install and your device are both configured (hypothetically) for UEFI. The article has info for repairing installs that go wrong.